# AS3 removing child with specific letter on its name

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to remove all child in my stage that starts with a specific letter.

e.g.

stage.removechild(a*)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you would need to iterate over all child objects and identify the one that fulfill the given criteria and then remove them for example with `removeChild(toBeRemove)` with  `toBeRemove` being the object you want to remove.

There is no `removeChild()` overload for what you want to do, if there was it should look like `removeChild("a*")` anyway. I suppose you want to take the name as a criteria, taking the actual variable name as criteria is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Iterate through all the children.
// Backward loop to not miss children if any of them gets removed.
for (var i:int = stage.numChildren - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    // Get a reference to a child.
    var aChild:DisplayObject = stage.getChildAt(i);

    // Check its name and remove if condition is met.
    if (aChild.name.charAt(0) == "a") stage.removeChildAt(i);
}
```

Keep in mind that this will check and remove **only** children that are attached to the **stage** directly. Those attached to **root** or deeper will not be affected.